# How to variabilize a VARIABLE NAME with Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm currently working with this loop:

```
@{someList}=    Create List    A    B    C    D    E
FOR    ${j}    IN    @{someList}
        FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    999999
            ${randomString}=    Generate Random String    4    0123456789
            Set Suite Variable    ${nameItem${j}}    ${randomString}
            Set Suite Variable    ${refItem${j}}    ${randomString}/${date}
            ${myItem}=    GET    ${urlAPI}${urlItem}/${refItem**${j}**}
            ${condition}=    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure
            ...    The randomString number does not exist
            IF    "${condition}"=="True"    BREAK
        END
    END
```

I need to generate variable names dynamically, by catenating the name of the item and another name from a list.
The issue I'm facing is that the loop itself works fine as is with Robot on VSCode, but I have to copy the code in SquashTM, which will the lead to a message error beacuse of the variable format (Squash only accepts letters, numbers and dashes in the parameter names).

So because of SquashTM I have to rework my code in order to change the variable names. I still need the names to be set dynamically because I will reuse theme late rin the code.

How can I catenate 2 strings in order to form a dynamic variable **name**? I've tried to make a specific keyword but with no success. I'm a noob so sometimes I don't undestand how things work! Also, I can't install other tools for automation due to my company policy.

Thanks in advance for yout help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Catenate

```
${new_var}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${string1}    text1    ${string2}    text2
```